# End conversation feedback in azure bot using c#

Tags: c#, azure, bots, user-feedback

I am using the Azure bot framework , SDK v4.0 and for publishing use the teams channel .Please help me out to take feedback from user and store in cosmos DB which is occur at the end of the conversation between bot and user in teams channel.

Comment: Welcome to SO  To enable others on SO to help you, you should provide more detailed information on you problem. You could for example do this by adding screenshots or code snippets to your question

Answer (score 0):

The SDK provides built in implementations for Azure Services (Blob, Cosmos DB, etc.) as well as external storage systems (MongoDB, MySQL, etc.). After you have run your bot and save your information, we can view the data stored in the Azure portal under the Data Explorer tab.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#add-a-database) for the same.